# Pull items from nested object virtuals into the parent object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

I'd like to take this array of objects, where some objects contain arrays of a similar schema, and create a new array where they're all on the same level.

```
[
  {
   "name": "United States",
   "slug": "united-states",
   "states":[
     {
      "name": "Arizona",
      "slug": "arizona"
     },
     {
      "name": "California",
      "slug": "california"
     }
    ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Canada",
   "slug": "canada",
  }

]
```

This should be the end result:

```
[
  {
   "name": "United States",
   "slug": "united-states"
  },
  {
   "name": "Arizona",
   "slug": "arizona"
  },
  {
   "name": "California",
   "slug": "california"
  },
  {
   "name": "Canada",
   "slug": "canada",
  }

]
```

Comment: What have you tried for this? Also, your input could de deeply nested give some basic idea as to how complex it could be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap):

```js
const data = [
  {
    "name": "United States",
    "slug": "united-states",
    "states":[
      { "name": "Arizona", "slug": "arizona" },
      { "name": "California", "slug": "california" }
    ]
  },
  { "name": "Canada", "slug": "canada" }
];

const res = data.flatMap(({ name, slug, states = [] }) => ([
  { name, slug },
  ...states
]));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Getting a "flatMap is not a function" error in Nuxt, asyncData lifecycle, trying to figure out why I don't have access to that function here

Comment: Can you share more details on the use case and the error

Answer (score 0):

You could create an iterator for traversing the tree, and than consume that into an array. This works with deeper nesting levels, and does not need to know which property has the child records. It assumes that the property which has an Array value is holding the subtrees:

```js
function * traverse(forest) {
    for (const item of forest) {
        const arrayKey = Object.entries(item).find(([k, v]) => Array.isArray(v))?.[0];
        const { [arrayKey]: children, ...rest } = item;
        yield rest;
        if (children) yield * traverse(children);
    }
}

const data = [{"name": "United States","slug": "united-states","states":[{ "name": "Arizona", "slug": "arizona" },{ "name": "California", "slug": "california" }]},{ "name": "Canada", "slug": "canada" }];

const res = [...traverse(data)];

console.log(res);
```